# How to install gcp in Python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Lots of the BigQuery examples begin with:

```
import gcp.bigquery as bq
```

But I get `ImportError: No module named gcp.bigquery` whenever I try to run this.

How do I install this library?

I'm working in a virtualenv with python 2.7. I've tried `pip install gcp`, `pip install gcloud`, and `pip install google-api-python-client`.

None of them help and I can't find any documentation. Help!

UPDATE: the reason I want to use `gcp` is that I want to get data from BigQuery, preferably in CSV form, from within a Python script. If there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try a simple:

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

as discussed in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/bigquery/v2).

Furthermore, `gcp.bigquery` is part of [Google Cloud DataLab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/getting-started), so you should try from that angle if you are still interested.

Answer (score 3):

Use pandas and google-api-python-client. The function you are looking for is pd.read_gbq http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq.html

Answer (score 3):

For anyone with this problem, it looks like the datalabs library was updated and now you should import things differently.

```
import datalab.bigquery as bq
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're accessing BigQuery in python, you can do that using the [`gcloud`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) library.

First, install the `gcloud` library:

```
$ pip install --upgrade gcloud
```

Then, after setting up your [auth and project info](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html#authentication-configuration), you can make api calls in python like this (adapted from the [gcloud-python docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html)):

```
from gcloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
datasets, next_page_token = client.list_datasets()
print([dataset.name for dataset in datasets])
```

(As someone mentioned previously, you can also do it [using the google-api-python-client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart).)

License: [Apache 2](https://developers.google.com/open-source/devplat)

Answer (score 1):

gcp.bigquery is a library specific to Cloud Datalab (as would be any samples you saw such an import in).

Answer (score 1):

You can build the library from datalab teams' content on github:

1. Clone the repository https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/
2. Run tools/initenv.sh
3. Run sources/build.sh
4. There you have it under sources/build/

Hope this helps. Executing the docker image locally does not work for me at least.